# Should I rasterio.open the destination when reprojecting raster?

Tags: python, rasterio

I use the code:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

mask=rasterio.open(path1)
dst_crs='EPSG:4326'
with rasterio.open(path2) as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, mask.width, mask.height, *mask.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
        })

    with rasterio.open(pathdst, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.transform,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

that gives now an error `RasterioIOError: Blacklisted: file cannot be opened by driver 'netCDF' in 'w' mode`.

My src file is multibanded, so I wat to reproject all bands at a time. Mask file should give all information for transformations. What is the shortest and the most pythonic way to do that?
Note: my files have no SRS (it is None).

After comment:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling
from netCDF4 import Dataset

mask=rasterio.open(path1)
dst_crs='EPSG:4326'
with rasterio.open(path2) as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, mask.width, mask.height, *mask.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
        })

    dst=Dataset(pathdst, "w", format="NETCDF4")
    for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
        reproject(
            source=rasterio.band(src, i),
            destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
            src_transform=src.transform,
            src_crs=src.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=dst_crs,
            resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

so what is the way to adress to bands with netCDF4? There is nothing about it in the docs.
Of course it gives an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-dbd35e15c61a> in <module>
     21         reproject(
     22             source=rasterio.band(src, i),
---> 23             destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
     24             src_transform=src.transform,
     25             src_crs=src.crs,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py in band(ds, bidx)
    251     rasterio.Band
    252     """
--> 253     return Band(ds, bidx, set(ds.dtypes).pop(), ds.shape)
    254 
    255 

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__getattr__()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.getncattr()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._get_att()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()

AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [rasterio.drivers module](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.drivers.html?highlight=%20blacklisted#rasterio.drivers.is_blacklisted) and in the file [rasterio: drivers.py](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/drivers.py), it is specified:

> NetCDF writing, for example, is presently blacklisted. Rasterio users
>   should use netcdf4-python instead:
>   http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/.

Comment: Well, it's a good note. See pls the 2nd code above

Comment: it is another question

Comment: you mean, I should close this one and start an another?

Comment: yes, a second question's go